# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource when sending post request

Tags: javascript, html, iis, oauth-2.0, cors

I try to use github oauth 2.0. As my website doesn't have a backend, I use XMLHttpRequest to send a post request, but I get the following error when sending post request to get access_token:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Here's my source code.

index.html

```
<a href="https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxx&scope=user,public_repo">login</a>
```

functions.js

```
function getQueryVariable(variable) {} //This works well.
function sendPost()
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token';
    var params = 'client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx&code='+code;
    http.open('POST', url, true);
    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            alert(http.responseText);
        }
    }
    http.send(params);
}
```

login.html

```
<script src=functions.js></script>
<script>
var code=getQueryVariable("code");
console.log(code);
</script>
<script>
sendPost();
</script>
```

Comment: I use iis as a server.

Comment: I have also tried to put these code to a true domain instead of localhost.

Comment: Is there a method to request by proxy?

Answer (score -2):

Please do a quick read-up on CORS.

Most likely .. you have enable CORS.

https://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled

Comment: But I cannot set attributes of response.

Comment: I doubt the OP owns the github server, therefore the OP has no way to enable CORS